# LNK 2005 error in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, linker-errors, googletest, lnk2005

I use Visual Studio 2005 on windows XP.
I'm trying to use "Google Test" framework. But i couldn't manage to make just one test because of linker errors.

I built Google Test source files with /MDd option in Debug mode
Than i created new project.
Then made the steps written in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005) to the project properties file.

Than i tried to build in Debug mode with /MDd option and following errors occured.
Can you help please?
Thank you.

```
 #include "gtest/gtest.h"
TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    return 1;
}


1>------ Build started: Project: try3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>try3.cpp
1>Linking...
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(void)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::facet::facet_Register(class std::locale::facet *)" (?facet_Register@facet@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,char const *)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@PBD@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int)" (??2@YAPAXIABU_DebugHeapTag_t@std@@PADH@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new[](unsigned int,struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const &,char *,int)" (??_U@YAPAXIABU_DebugHeapTag_t@std@@PADH@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>libcpmtd.lib(xdebug.obj) : error LNK2005: "struct std::_DebugHeapTag_t const & __cdecl std::_DebugHeapTag_func(void)" (?_DebugHeapTag_func@std@@YAABU_DebugHeapTag_t@1@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtSetCheckCount already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(void)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::exception::exception(class std::exception const &)" (??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual char const * __thiscall std::exception::what(void)const " (?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(char const *)" (??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::bad_cast::bad_cast(class std::bad_cast const &)" (??0bad_cast@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::bad_cast::~bad_cast(void)" (??1bad_cast@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(osfinfo.obj) : error LNK2005: __open_osfhandle already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dosmap.obj) : error LNK2005: __errno already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(_file.obj) : error LNK2005: ___iob_func already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __decode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(fflush.obj) : error LNK2005: _fflush already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(lconv.obj) : error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(stricmp.obj) : error LNK2005: __stricmp already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _sprintf_s already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(getenv.obj) : error LNK2005: _getenv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(strtol.obj) : error LNK2005: _strtol already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(strtoq.obj) : error LNK2005: __strtoui64 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgrptw.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtDbgReportW already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(printf.obj) : error LNK2005: _printf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(vprintf.obj) : error LNK2005: _vprintf already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR80D.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>c:\try3\try3\Debug\try3.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\try3\try3\try3\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>try3 - 57 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When i comment gtest file the error is below:

```
//#include "gtest/gtest.h"

1>------ Build started: Project: try3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>try3.cpp
1>c:\try3\try3\try3\try3.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'sample_test_case' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\try3\try3\try3\try3.cpp(6) : error C2065: 'sample_test' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\try3\try3\try3\try3.cpp(7) : error C2448: 'TEST' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\try3\try3\try3\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>try3 - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By working hours, I solved this problem by adding

"Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Ignore Specific Library"

"msvcprtd.lib;MSVCRTD.lib" libraries.

Comment: I found this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005 -- it goes through static vs dynamic linking.