# What's the difference between gtest.lib and gtest_main.lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker, googletest

Google's C++ Test Framework has two output libraries: one is gtest.lib and the other one is gtest_main.lib. According to [Nik Reiman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005/533372#533372) on [how to setup gtest with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005), we should link to gtest_main.lib but I'm linking to gtest.lib and the sample test cases that I have are running fine.

What's the difference between the two libraries and does it matter which one I link to?

Comment: This minimal example might clarify things a bit as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/97626/how-to-install-googletest/1295185#1295185

Answer (score 38, accepted):

the only reasonable difference is that **gtest_main.lib** provides a default implementation of a test application entry point (i.e. `main` function):

Citation from [Getting started with Google C++ Testing Framework](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/primer.md):

> "[...] maybe you think that writing
> all those main() functions is too much
> work? We agree with you completely and
> that's why Google Test provides a
> basic implementation of main(). If it
> fits your needs, then just link your
> test with gtest_main library and you
> are good to go."

If you want to write your main function yourself - you should link with **gtest.lib**.

Comment: Copy/paste of `main()` is more work than setting up your project to link gtest_main.lib?  I'd argue that it's not. Anyway, thanks for the quote. I was wondering why it was done this way.

Comment: gtest_main is **not** an alternative to gtest. You need to link with gtest if you want to use the library either way. If you also want the default main implementation, also link with gtest_main.

Comment: I'm having a problem setting up gtest to work on my solution. I've added a new project (copied source from one of the samples), added relevant include and linking directories, and specified gtest.lib and gtest_main.lib to link against. If I build my project as a .dll, the tests aren't discovered, and if I build as .exe I have no entry point defined. How do I set-up my project to use gtest_main main() function as the entry point?

Comment: @TamásSzelei - that doesn't seem to be the case at least for the `make` build in release 1.8 (most recent release as of today). The corresponding dependencies are `gtest-all.o gtest_main.o` and `gtest-all.o` for `gtest_main` and `gtest` respectively, so `gtest_main` is a superset of `gtest` and includes all the gtest functionality.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I don't think that this changed, although I used the cmake build. In the current master commit gtest_main is not a superset of gtest: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/CMakeLists.txt#L91

Comment: Interesting. It seems that the `cmake` and `make` builds are simply inconsistent. The `Makefile` is [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/make/Makefile) and clearly links in `gtest-all.o` for `gtest.a`. Since `cmake` seems to be the recommended way to build going forward, I would assume that the most likely intention is that you gtest_main **not** include the rest of the code, as you mentioned. @TamásSzelei

Comment: @TamásSzelei - it was confusing enough I wrote an answer about it. I think that googletest has unnecessarily confused things, but the below should fully cover it.

Comment: @BeeOnRope wow, good find. I think this is worth reporting as a bug.

Comment: @TamásSzelei, filed: https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/1015 - although with 354 open issues I don't have too much hope for a speedy resolution.

Answer (score 12):

In fact, the various build methods available for googletest don't build the libraries consistently. At least this part is consistent though:

### gtest

The gtest library (variously called `gtest.a`, `gtest.so`, `gtest.lib` or `libgtest.a`, etc, depending on your platform and whether you are using the shared library) contains the object code for the gtest framework, including everything that tests need. Basically it implements everything you can use from `gtest/gest.h`. It **does not** include a `main()` method.

### gtest_main

It includes a trivial main method that will launch the registered tests, something like this (as of 1.8):

```
GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n");
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Now the inconsistent part is that `gtest_main` sometimes *also* includes everything from `gtest`, so that you *only* need to link against *either* `gtest` (if you want to write your own `main()` method) *or* `gtest_main` (if you want the use the canned main method above). This is the case, for example, if you use the `Makefile` build included in [`googletest/make`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/make/Makefile):

```
gtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

gtest_main.a : gtest-all.o gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
```

Clearly, `gtest_main.a` includes everything that `gtest.a` does, *plus* the `gtest-main.o` object which includes the main function.

With the CMake build, however, the situation is different, at least for some build artifacts. For example, for the main libraries [we have](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/CMakeLists.txt#L82):

```
cxx_library(gtest "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest-all.cc)
cxx_library(gtest_main "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest_main.cc)
target_link_libraries(gtest_main gtest)
```

Here, `gtest_main` *only* contains the main function and nothing much else<sup>1</sup>. The `target_link_libraries` line tells anything else *using this CMake build* that if you link `gtest_main` you should also link `gtest`, so in the rest of the file it is common to see things linked only against `gtest_main`. Indeed, the documentation earlier in the `CMakeLists.txt` file makes this explicit:

```
# Defines the gtest & gtest_main libraries.  User tests should link
# with one of them.
```

Note the "with one one them" part. What they really mean is that if you are building with this same CMake system you can do that, but at the actual link level you need both `libtest.a` and `libgtest_main.a` or else you won't pull in what you need to write a test.

---

<sup>1</sup> Indeed, with CMake libgtest.a ends up at 1,755,216 bytes, and libgtest_main.a is only a paltry 3,836 bytes. With the `../make/Makefile` build, those figures are 3,365,240 and 3,398,356 respectively. Evidently there are differences beyond the files included that blow up the size of the `Makefile` version.

Answer (score -4):

You will need to link `gtest.lib` to your project with the unit tests.