# Googletest never fails (where it should) with bazel test but works with cmake & clion

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, googletest, bazel

I am trying to use [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest) with [bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html) and cmake.

The cmake and clion works perfect as for the test part, it fails where it should fail and passes where it should pass.
However, `bazel test` will pass all the tests even they should not.

### Bazel test not working

For example, I have the `stupid_test.cc` file:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(StupidTests, Stupid1) {
  EXPECT_EQ(100, 20);
  EXPECT_TRUE(false);
}
```

which should fail always.

The bazel `BUILD` file:

```
cc_test(
    name = "stupid_test",
    srcs = ["stupid_test.cc"],
    deps = [
        "//bazel_build/googletest:gtest",
    ],
)
```

where `bazel_build/googletest` is exactly the same files downloaded from the googletest github.

Then I run `bazel test :stupid_test`, the output is:

```
⇒  blaze test :stupid_test
DEBUG: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_myusername/741c62b201e51840aa320b156e05fd70/external/bazel_tools/tools/osx/xcode_configure.bzl:87:9: Invoking xcodebuild failed, developer dir: /Users/honghaoli/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer ,return code 1, stderr: xcrun: error: invalid DEVELOPER_DIR path (/Users/honghaoli/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer), missing xcrun at: /Users/honghaoli/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun
, stdout: 
INFO: Analysed target //:stupid_test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
Target //:stupid_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/stupid_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.840s, Critical Path: 1.55s
INFO: 4 processes: 4 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4 total actions
//:stupid_test                                                           PASSED in 0.1s

Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4 total actions
```

I have no idea why it passed.

### CMake Works

The same test file would fail with very clear message using cmake and clion. For example, part of the CMakeLists

```
add_executable(stupid_test stupid_test.cc)
target_link_libraries(stupid_test gtest gtest_main)
add_test(NAME stupid_test COMMAND stupid_test)
```

and the output fail message:

```
Testing started at 19:16 ...
/Users/myusername...blabla/cmake-build-debug/stupid_test --gtest_filter=* --gtest_color=no
Running main() from /Users/myusername...blabla/cmake-build-debug/googletest-src/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite./Users/myusername...blabla/stupid_test.cc:11: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  100
  20
/Users/myusername...blabla/stupid_test.cc:12: Failure
Value of: false
  Actual: false
Expected: true

/Users/myusername...blabla/stupid_test.cc:13: Failure
Value of: true
  Actual: true
Expected: false


Process finished with exit code 1
```

*I am using the Mac OS 10.14 if that helps.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason.

Just change

```
"//bazel_build/googletest:gtest",
```

in the `BUILD` file into

```
"//bazel_build/googletest:gtest_main",
```

I'm still confused! 
If the `gtest` does not work, it should at least fail the build or throw error/warnings. It should never say:

```
Executed 1 out of 1 test: 1 test passes.
```

as the output.

I consider it as a bug.

Comment: A relevant post but not the answer for my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457856/whats-the-difference-between-gtest-lib-and-gtest-main-lib).