# Automated testing for an MFC based user interface

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, testing, mfc, automated-tests

I am looking to run a load of automated functionality tests on a user interface application of mine and was wondering what is the best software out there to carry out these tests. Preferably the software will be able to intergrate with Visuall C++ 2005. I have googled various software however there is so much out there I'm not sure what is best for what I need. Any help would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for automated software unit tests I would recommend google test. There is a very good q&a on this platform, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005).

Additionally, there is CPPUnitLite, which is developed by the author of "[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)", Michael Feathers.

I used AutoIt Scripts for testing a MFC application just a little bit, but it was not that easy to maintain them properly and build an effective logging system for failed tests.

However, the unit tests depend heavily on the architecture of your program and the structure of your class - especially the dependencies to other components / classes. So if you already have an existing MFC application, which was not built with unit tests in mind, you probably have to refactor a lot of things. Therefore, I would recommend the mentioned book. You can also use the classic "[Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)" by Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)? It's a generic GUI scripting language which can also be used from C++/C#. I'm using it to automate parts of testing a Visual Studio addin.

Comment: I was looking something more like  unit tests, I will give this a go though.