# How to setup googletest on Linux in the year 2012?

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, googletest

I am using Linux machine.
I have download the googletest package from [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/downloads/detail?name=gtest-1.6.0.zip)

However, there is no installation guide or other blogs related on how to set it up properly
The README file is no good that I can't understand what it is talking about?

Can anyone provide a simple example on how to test a simple function inside a .cc file with that gtest package?

Answer (score 14):

Here's what I did and you can adjust as necessary.  I downloaded gtest-1.6.0.zip (from the [releases](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases) page) on my Linux box into ~/Downloads which typed out fully is /home/me/Downloads/

Unzip the contents of gtest-1.6.0.zip into ~/Downloads/gtest-1.6.0/

```
cd /home/me/Downloads
unzip gtest-1.6.0.zip
```

Build the gtest library because it's something you need to "include" in your test executable.
Compile the object file gtest-all.o:

```
g++ -Igtest-1.6.0/include -Igtest-1.6.0 -c gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc
```

Then build the library archive libgtest.a:

```
ar -rv libgtest.a gtest-all.o
```

Now you can create your test.cc file in ~/Downloads.  Here is an example test file that I used to make sure it compiles.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(blahTest, blah1) {
    EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    int returnValue;

    //Do whatever setup here you will need for your tests here
    //
    //

    returnValue =  RUN_ALL_TESTS();

    //Do Your teardown here if required
    //
    //

    return returnValue;
}
```

To compile your own test and run it:

```
g++ -I/home/me/Downloads/gtest-1.6.0/include -pthread test.cc libgtest.a -o test_executable
```

Then to execute it:

```
./test_executable
```

And it should run fine.  Modify as necessary from there.

Comment: Note that building the library using `gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc` will require you to provide with a main method. If you want to avoid that altogether and use the default implementation of the main method, build your library using `gtest_main.cc` instead.

Answer (score 3):

These instructions get the testing framework working for the Debug configuration.

**Get Google C++ Testing Framework**

1.Download the latest gtest framework

2.Unzip to `C:\gtest`

**Build the Framework Libraries**

1.Open `C:\gtest\msvc\gtest.sln` in Visual Studio

2.Set Configuration to "Debug"

3.Build Solution

**Create and Configure Your Test Project**

1.Create a new solution and choose the template Visual C++ > Win32 > Win32 Console Application

2.Right click the newly created project and choose Properties

3.Change Configuration to Debug.

4.Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories: Add `C:\gtest\include`

5.Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library: If your code links to a runtime DLL, choose Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd). If not, choose Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).

6.Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories: Add `C:\gtest\msvc\gtest\Debug`

7.Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies: Add `gtestd.lib`

**Verifying Everything Works**

1.Open the cpp in your Test Project containing the `main()` function.

2.Paste the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

    TEST(sample_test_case, sample_test)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
    { 
        testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv); 
        RUN_ALL_TESTS(); 
        std::getchar(); // keep console window open until Return keystroke
    }
```

1.Debug > Start Debugging

If this works you should see the console window open with your test results.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but Do you have the solution for linux environment?

Comment: Oh i apologise, didn't see Linux in there.

Comment: I need the the steps for windows setup. Thanks for this.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this answer taken from this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005. if yes, I would mention a reference to the original answer

Answer (score 1):

An addendum to [James C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978127/6314615):

Note that building the library using `gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc` will require you to provide with a main method yourself. If you want to avoid that altogether and use the default implementation of the main method provided by Googletest, build your library including `gtest_main.cc`.

That is:

```
g++ -Igtest-1.6.0/include -Igtest-1.6.0 -c gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest-all.cc gtest-1.6.0/src/gtest_main.cc
                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ar -rv libgtest_main.a gtest_main.o gtest-all.o
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, keep in mind that implementing your own main method is **not** the recommended way of defining the `SetUp` and `TearDown` behaviours; you should be using fixtures instead. Check the [Googletest documentation on the topic](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#test-fixtures-using-the-same-data-configuration-for-multiple-tests).