# Is there any way to make Google testing framework work with Visual Studio 6?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, googletest

I tried to follow [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005) but have gotten lots of compilation errors like this.

```
error C2182: '__formal' : illegal use of type 'void'
```

Is there anybody who is successfully using VS 6.0 with Google Testing?

Comment: Is there anybody who is successfully using VS 6.0?

Comment: VS6's successor has been available for a few weeks shy of a decade. You should use its distant, distant descendant VS2010 or VS2011. Wait, let me guess.. you're on Windows 98 SE, too?

Comment: @MikeSeymour and Lightness I am laughing with you but there are still some organizations using it. You might be surprised to see how many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago, someone [proposed](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/googletestframework/JaSzLnwVDo8/discussion) a patch for Google Test to support VC6. That patch was ultimately rejected in the trunk because it made it harder to support the library.  But the patched source was put in a branch in Subversion for people who need it.  [There](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/#svn/branches/unsupported-vc6-port) it sits, unsupported.

But because it's not supported, there has been no backports from the trunk since it was branched at version 1.3. But if you really need it and don't mind missing all the features added since then, you can grab it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. VS 6.0 isn't compatible with C++03, so not much C++ will work on it. You'll most likely need at least VS 7.1 (2003) or VS 8.0 (2005).