# Running gtest using Visual Studio 2010: LNK4098 and LNK2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest

I have installed google test as it'is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531941/how-to-setup-google-c-testing-framework-gtest-on-visual-studio-2005). But when I try to use tests for my current project, I get 2 LNK4098 warnings:

defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library

and the same for 'LIBCMTD', and a bunch of LNK2005 errors. But when I actually ignore these two default libraries, it doesn't help: I get even more errors. What's the problem?

Comment: Did you read in the answers you linked to how everything must be built using the same runtime library configuration?  The error you're getting sounds like some parts are built using the non-debug runtime and others built using the debug runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to ensure googletest and your project are built using the same version of the C Runtime Library (CRT).  Google test (currently v1.6.0) provides 2 Visual Studio solution files; `gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest.sln` which uses the static version and `gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md.sln` which uses the dynamic (dll) version.  By default, projects created via Visual Studio use the dll version.

You need to decide whether you want your project to use the static or dynamic versions of the CRT.

To set your project to use the static versions, go to `Project->Properties` and at the top left of the window, select Configuration: `Debug`.  Then in this same window select `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Code Generation`.  The option for `Runtime Library` should be `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`.

You then need to ensure you're linking to the appropriate versions of gtest, so select `Configuration Properties` -> `Linker` -> `Input`.  Edit the `Additional Dependencies` field by providing the full path to the Debug version of the gtest library (e.g. `C:\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest\Debug\gtestd.lib`).

Do the same again for Release Configuration, but setting the `Runtime Library` option to `Multi-threaded (/MT)` and providing the full path to the Release version of the gtest library (e.g. `C:\gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest\Release\gtest.lib`).

If you decide you want to use the dll versions of the CRT, choose `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` and `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`, and link to the gtest-md libraries which will be in `gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest-md\...` rather than `gtest-1.6.0\msvc\gtest\...`.